# Brakeman: Mass Assignment not restricted using attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, brakeman

I totally understand what "Mass assignment" means and if a model does not contain any fields under `attr_accessible` , it will give the warning in the title.

Now I have this scenario.
I have a model that has just 2 columns, `user_id` and `company_id`.
I am making sure that while instantiating a instance of this model, I am not using Mass assignment.
Instead I am going for `new + save`.

But Since brakeman does not find any `attr_accessible` in this model , I add the below line in the model:

`attr_accessible :user_id, :company_id`

Post the above code, the previous issue gets fixed but brakeman comes up with one more warning: 
Potentially dangerous attribute available for Mass assignment.

So what should I do in this case. I dont want to get any issues related to Mass Assignment.

Thanks.

Comment: what rails version are you using? `attr_accessible` in rails 4 is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using mass assignment, then you can just call `attr_accessible` without any arguments:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible
end
```

This prevents any mass assignment with the model.

Comment: Thanks, this one makes sense and my brakeman report also comes clear.
I  just need to make sure that I dont use Mass assignment with this mode.

Comment: I think this solution *will* make sure that you don't use mass assignment in this model!